# how to make a default call to a Asynchronous Datasource in case of angular bootstrap multiselect

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, q

I am using AngularJS with webAPIController. I have a multiselect dropdown list. For this i am following [This URL](https://bentorfs.github.io/angular-bootstrap-multiselect/#example-async). This URL fulfill my demand except a little bit. I need multiselect dropdownlist which will be populated from asynchronous datasource. For this I Used the following code

In HTML

```
<multiselect ng-model="vm.selectedRoles" options="vm.options" id-prop="roleCode" display-prop="roleName" show-search="true">
                                </multiselect>
```

In JS

```
 this.options = function() {
        return $q(function (resolve, reject) {
            ajaxService.ajaxPost(null, "api/UserRole/GetRoles", function (response) {
                resolve(response)
            }, this.getRolesOnError);                
        });
    }
```

In WebAPIController

```
    [Route("GetRoles")]
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult GetRoles(HttpRequestMessage request, [FromBody] Role role)
    {
        List<Role> roles = _roleRepository.All.ToList();
        return Ok(roles);
    }
```

The following picture depicts my problem[image]

No options are available here but when i type something in the search field the function of WebAPIController called.[image]

But i need to call that function of WebAPIController with out typing anything in the search field

How can i do this. Please help. Any suggestion is highly appreciated

Comment: Are you looking at something like this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34779136/assign-default-value-to-multiselect-dropdown-using-angularjs ?

Comment: <<<i load the Items[] from javascript callback function, it does't work. but when i hard code the Item value, it works>>>

That looks like a timing issue OR a call back issue. Do you mind showing your code for that?

Comment: It may be a timing issue OR a call back issue. Here is my code                            <multiselect ng-model="vm.selectedRoles" options="vm.options" id-prop="roleCode" display-prop="roleName" show-search="true">
                                    </multiselect>

Comment: this.initializeController = function () {
            ajaxService.ajaxPost(null, "api/UserRole/GetRoles", this.getRolesOnSuccess, this.getRolesOnError);
        }

       this.getRolesOnSuccess= function (response) {
           // var Opts = JSON.parse(response);
            //vm.Options = Opts 
            vm.Options = response;
        }
        this.getRolesOnError= function () { }

Comment: And what is the hardcoded option that works?

Comment: [{"relatedPages":[{"pageCode":"HOME","pageName":"Entry Page","pageURL":"/","pageDescription":"Entry","id":1,"makeBy":"5498","createDate":"2016-07-26T00:00:00","checkBy":"5498","checkerDate":"2016-07-26T00:00:00","lastUpdatedBy":"5498","lastUpdateDate":"2016-07-26T00:00:00"}],"roleCode":"APPMKR","roleName":"Application Maker","description":"Author to create User","id":1,"makeBy":"5498","createDate":"2016-07-26T00:00:00","checkBy":"5498","checkerDate":"2016-07-26T00:00:00","lastUpdatedBy":"5498","lastUpdateDate":"2016-07-26T00:00:00"}]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118755/discussion-between-alfred-ace-and-arungeorge).